# Datastax - Transactions are not supported

Tags: cassandra, datastax, pyodbc

I have installed Cassandra ODBC Driver and I've setup DSN.
While trying to connect as below

```python
**conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=Sample DataStax Cassandra DSN;UID=***;PWD=***;autocommit=True')**
```

I get the error

> pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [DataStax][ODBC] (11470) Transactions
>   are not supported. (11470) (SQLSetConnnectAttr(SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT))')

What am I missing here?

Comment: Read through http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/odbc-driver/doc/ ? Also if you can at all possibly avoid it, avoid the odbc driver and use native driver. It will never work remotely as well.

Answer (score 1):

Probably trying to set the `autocommit` value is triggering an issue. Cassandra doesn't have transactions so I'm guessing that the driver writer wanted to make clear that `autocommit` was impossible on Cassandra.

So I would remove the `autocommit` parameter.

Comment: I get the same error even after removing autocommit

Comment: With set attr autocommit?

Comment: I got nothing then, but I would also recommend using the python driver over the odbc connector.